# What characters do I need to escape when doing a SOQL query?

Tags: soql, ruby

I'm attempting to create a Ruby on Rails application using `Restforce`, but the `query` method doesn't support prepared statements. So I need to escape each input that I put into the query myself. What characters do I need to escape from each input before sending the query to Salesforce? Can I use the [Regex.escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) function, or do I need to escape other characters as well?

Comment: It might just be single quotes that need to be escaped with a backslash. . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few characters you need to escape when calling SOQL and SOSL, including ', \, _, and % (for some queries only). For more information about escape sequences, see [Quoted String Escape Sequences](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm). You might also be required to escape XML-unsafe characters, such as <, >, and " if you're using the SOAP API, or URL-unsafe characters, such as %, @, and so on, when using the REST API. Refer to the specific SOAP/REST library you're using to determine if any additional escapes are required.

Answer (score 4):

I've been doing this in C# for years now with the SOAP API and now I'm carrying it over to the REST API:

```
public static string SoqlEscape(string plain)
{
    return plain.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("'", "\\'").Replace("\"", "\\\"");
}
```

I run my parameter values through it, like so:

```
string soql = string.Format("select id from lead where email = '{0}'",
                            sf.SoqlEscape(email));
```

It replaces `\` with `\\` (has to happen first obviously), `'` with `\'`, and `"` with `\"`. This is not just to prevent malicious injection, but also to **accurately represent text in queries**. Incredibly rare I'm sure, but Workbench gives very different results for the escaped `select subject from case where subject like '%C:\\%'` and unescaped `select subject from case where subject like '%C:\%'` query.

Answer (score 2):

There are some additional character patterns that end up escaping as well, so it is worth being mindful of them. In addition, it sounds like if you use a single backslash without having one of the sequences listed (and not escaping it) the query will break.

[image]

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm